# Error Using boost ASIO library compiled by Mingw 5.3 using QT

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, mingw32

I compiled boost library using Mingw 5.3 comes with QT5.10.0 using this command

```
bootstrap gcc
b2 toolset=gcc
```

then I test some of its libraries as date time and file system and it worked fine. now I want to try to use the network library asio, so I linked that library using QT, by add library from right click on the project -> add library I add those

```
boost.regex
boost.system
boost.thread
boost.date_time
```

which comes in the boost documentation to link that library to use asio library [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html)
I got this error when i make a simple hello world app contains only the header

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

when i compiled i got this error.

```
D:\Build\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw53-mt-x32-1_66.a(error_code.o):-1: error: duplicate section     `.rdata$_ZTIN5boost6system14error_category12std_categoryE[__ZTIN5boost6system14error_category12std_categoryE]' has different size

D:\Build\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw53-mt-x32-1_66.a(error_code.o):-1: error: duplicate section `.rdata$_ZTVN5boost6system14error_category12std_categoryE[__ZTVN5boost6system14error_category12std_categoryE]' has different size

: error: undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'

: error: undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'

: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

also i got some failed and skipped after I finish compiling boost library using Mingw 5.3.0 which comes with QT. so I don't know if these affect my build to use asio and I test each library alone such as date and time regex and file system which needs system library and all worked. but boost thread give me the error of duplicated section like the above error
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need some punctuation. Without it your post makes no sense.

Comment: I think instead to downvote my post help with this punctuations or if there is nothing unclear ask me in the comment so i can edit my post and clear it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build with some additional libraries for Windows.
Try adding the following lines to your `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += -lgdi32
LIBS += -lwsock32
LIBS += -lws2_32
```

There are a couple of `.pro` files that build `boost asio` HTTP servers and clients on `Windows` with `MinGw 5.3` from `Qt` [here](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/tree/master/examples).